# I need simplest way to draw a line in java in AWT panel

Tags: java, user-interface

I need the simplest way to draw a line between to coordinates.
Since this drawing line in my code will be repeated more than 200 times in a loop i need the easiest way. I'm drawing the lines in a AWT panel component.

Comment: how about using `paintComponent()` and `Graphics2D`?

Comment: where should i look to learn about them?

Comment: I would recommend switching to [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to switch to Swing you would use the JPanel and overwrite the `paintComponent()` method.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelWithLine extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    }

}
```

You can than redraw everything by calling `repaint()` on your Jpanel. 
You would probably change the coordinates and then call the `repaint()` method in your loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I've used java.awt.Panel, but it should be something like:

```
class Foo extends Panel {
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    g.drawLine(x3,y3,x4,y4);
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `super.paint(g)`?